# vertical and horizontal responsive list

Tags: css

i want to ask you how can i make a responsive list with 3 items in wich when i reduce the size of my browser the items go vertical and the one is below the other, when the browser window is growing the items will be in one. My code for the list is the following , i managed to order them in center and in one row but i am getting confused about the responsive..

```
<div class="list">
<ul id="2" class="3">
<li><a href="#">< </a></li>
<li><a href="#"> </a></li>
<li><a href="#"> </a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

and the css

```
.list{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}

.list li {
    width: 33.3%; /* nice 3 columns */
    float: left;
    padding: 0; /* should have zero paddng/margin */
    margin: 0;
}

.list li > span {
 margin: 6% 6% 0 0; /* now margins are specified relative to outer <li> width */
 display: block;
}
```

Comment: You should take a look at css media queries: http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/ It allows you to specify different rules when the browser gets resized. Also if you are designing a responsive website you should take the mobile first approach. There are also frameworks out there that can do it for you...But I guess if you want to learn this is the best way :)

Comment: @Mikey: I would agree <somewhat> to your arguement: however saying you **should take the mobile first approach** is a complete lunacy, given the details. There are pros and cons for media queries, [see here](http://designshack.net/articles/css/mobilefirst/)

Comment: @jbutler483 "Should" is maybe too strong :)...I know there are limits but depending on the project it is worth considering though.

Comment: From the looks of the 'project' (probably more correctly called **snippet**, I do not see anywhere a suggestion for need of a mobile-first approach). It looks more suitable for a desktop-first approach (from use of the word ***browser***), and yet you suggest using media queries (as also suggested in the answers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for are css media queries. For example, add this to your css:

```
@media (max-width:500px){
    .list li {
        float:none;
   }
}
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cjL15ngc/).

Suggest you read this:

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/layouts/rwd-fundamentals/use-media-queries?hl=en
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries
http://cssmediaqueries.com/what-are-css-media-queries.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use media queries to set a breakpoint and set the ".list li" width to 100% when the window width is less than the size you want.

Here's a link about media queries: http://cssmediaqueries.com/